# Logging to multiple log files with Postsharp and log4net

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, log4net, autofac, postsharp

I have a system that get data (usually exe files and text files) from several service provider, and my system get this data and preform some work on it (basically analyse its behavior).

I'm using `Log4Net` to generate log files and I would like to have separate log file for each service provider.

Until now (as I have only one service provider) I used `Postsharp` to log / trace my system. Basically I created attributes that have this code in it:

```
Public class LogAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect 
{
     private static ILog = LogManager.GetLogger();

     public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionEventArgs eventArgs)
     {
           //Log some stuff...
     }

     //some other code
}
```

And I add this ,or this kind of attributes (I have different attributes to different logging policies that I'm having) and I attached this attributes to different methods / assemblies that I want to log.

**Question**

Can I use `Postsharp` to decode the relevant log file base on the service that use the method being logged? (some methods and classes being used by more then one service provider).

If it's help I'm using Autofac to inject my dependencies, so maybe I can resolve the the log in run-time?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitively choose a different log file according to the current class or namespace. I can't help you with Autofac or log4net but, regarding PostSharp, I would suggest to:

1. Make the log field a [NonSerialized] instance field (instead of a static one).
2. Override the RuntimeInitialize method and initialize the log field according to whatever you want (you will receive the MethodInfo of the target method as a parameter)

Comment: 10X for your answer. but Unfortunately it is not enough. Your suggestion helps when every class attached to specific logger, but if different providers using same class methods, I won't be able to know which provider call this method.

Comment: I think you should precise your question a little more. If the provider depends on the instance of the class being executed, I suppose the instance should implement an interface that expose this interface. Then, cast `args.Instance` to this interface and access the logger from there.